# Type-Error when transposing a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector

While trying to write a template function to transpose a std vector of vectors of a unique type I am catching the following error:

```
/home/reiner/Desktop/utd-dune/duneuro-tests/src/test_meg_forward.cc: In function ‘int run(const Dune::ParameterTree&)’:
/home/reiner/Desktop/utd-dune/duneuro-tests/src/test_meg_forward.cc:127:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘absolute_error(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<Dune::FieldVector<double, 3> > > >::value_type&, std::vector<double>&)’
     absoluteErrors.push_back(absolute_error(ana_direct[i], num_direct));
                                                                      ^
/home/reiner/Desktop/utd-dune/duneuro-tests/src/test_meg_forward.cc:46:3: note: candidate: template<class T> T absolute_error(const std::vector<TIN, std::allocator<_Tp> >&, const std::vector<TIN, std::allocator<_Tp> >&)
 T absolute_error(const std::vector<T> &num, const std::vector<T> &ana) {
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/reiner/Desktop/utd-dune/duneuro-tests/src/test_meg_forward.cc:46:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/reiner/Desktop/utd-dune/duneuro-tests/src/test_meg_forward.cc:127:70: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘TIN’ (‘Dune::FieldVector<double, 3>’ and ‘double’)
     absoluteErrors.push_back(absolute_error(ana_direct[i], num_direct));
```

The code I am using looks like

```
template <class T>
T absolute_error(const std::vector<T> &num, const std::vector<T> &ana) {
  std::vector<T> diff;
  std::transform(num.begin(), num.end(), ana.begin(), std::back_inserter(diff),
                 [](const T &a, const T &b) { return a - b; });
  return norm(diff);
}
```

Sadly my C++-skills are lacking so while trying to correct the function I do not find a suitable solution. Maybe someone of you guys can help me?

Here is the run-function

```
int run(const Dune::ParameterTree &config) {
  // set up driver
  auto driver = duneuro::MEEGDriverFactory<3>::make_meeg_driver(config);
  auto coils = duneuro::FieldVectorReader<double, 3>::read(config.sub("coils"));
  auto projections =
      duneuro::ProjectionsReader<double, 3>::read(config.sub("projections"));
  driver->setCoilsAndProjections(coils, projections);

  Dune::FieldVector<double, 3> center = config.get<Dune::FieldVector<double, 3>>("analytic_solution.center");
  // read dipoles
  auto dipoles = duneuro::DipoleReader<double, 3>::read(config.sub("dipoles"));

  // store output in an output tree
  Dune::OutputTree output(config.get<std::string>("output.filename") + "." +
                          config.get<std::string>("output.extension"));

  auto solution = driver->makeDomainFunction();


  std::vector<std::vector<Dune::FieldVector<double, 3>>> ana_data;
  std::vector<std::vector<Dune::FieldVector<double, 3>>> ana_direct;

  ana_data = MEGAnalytical(coils, dipoles, projections, center);
  ana_direct = transpose(ana_data);

  std::vector<double> absoluteErrors;
  std::vector<double> relativeErrors;
  std::vector<double> magnitudeErrors;
  std::vector<double> rdmErrors;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dipoles.size(); ++i) {

    // compute numerical solution direct
    driver->solveEEGForward(dipoles[i], *solution, config.sub("solution"));
    auto num_direct =
        driver->solveMEGForward(*solution, config.sub("solution"));

//    subtract_mean(num_direct);
//    subtract_mean(ana_direct);

    auto prefix = std::string("dipole_") + std::to_string(i) + ".";
    absoluteErrors.push_back(absolute_error(ana_direct[i], num_direct));
    output.set(prefix + "ae", absoluteErrors.back());
    relativeErrors.push_back(relative_error(ana_direct[i], num_direct));
    output.set(prefix + "re", relativeErrors.back());
    magnitudeErrors.push_back(magnitude_error(ana_direct[i], num_direct));
    output.set(prefix + "mag", magnitudeErrors.back());
    rdmErrors.push_back(rdm_error(ana_direct[i], num_direct));
    output.set(prefix + "rdm", rdmErrors.back());



    std::cout << "Numerical solution for dipole: " << i << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < num_direct.size() ; j++) {
     std::cout << num_direct[j] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Analytical solution for dipole: " << i << std::endl;
    for (int k = 0; k < coils.size() ; k++) {
     std::cout << ana_direct[i][k] << std::endl;
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Additional output of the vectors:

```
Numerical solution for dipole: 9
9.93612e-05
-2.18637e-05
6.85649e-06
-3.50191e-05
1.43691e-05
-6.86168e-06
-4.64204e-05
7.99942e-06
-1.08231e-06
-2.6123e-05
-2.74267e-05
2.41666e-05
-4.83157e-05
3.60448e-05
-1.84048e-05
Analytical solution for dipole: 9
9.82984e-05 -2.24329e-05 1.00409e-05
-3.21174e-05 1.75503e-05 -6.64402e-06
-4.35313e-05 1.11112e-05 -5.96633e-22
-2.33793e-05 -2.4205e-05 2.26704e-05
-5.0926e-05 3.72573e-05 -2.09367e-05
```

Comment: The error is occurring in `run(const Dune::ParameterTree&)`. Care you show us that function? Apparently, you're trying to call `absolute_error` with arguments of types `std::vector<Dune::FieldVector<..>>` and `std::vector<double>`, but `absolute_error` excepts the types of its arguments to match (hence _"deduced conflicting types (‘Dune::FieldVector<...>’ and ‘double’)"_).

Comment: I added the function. The problem is that I dont know how to procceed to change the type correctly. 

```
Numerical solution for dipole: 9
9.93612e-05
-2.18637e-05
6.85649e-06
-3.50191e-05
1.43691e-05
-6.86168e-06
-4.64204e-05
7.99942e-06
-1.08231e-06
-2.6123e-05
-2.74267e-05
2.41666e-05
-4.83157e-05
3.60448e-05
-1.84048e-05
Analytical solution for dipole: 9
9.82984e-05 -2.24329e-05 1.00409e-05
-3.21174e-05 1.75503e-05 -6.64402e-06
-4.35313e-05 1.11112e-05 -5.96633e-22
-2.33793e-05 -2.4205e-05 2.26704e-05
-5.0926e-05 3.72573e-05 -2.09367e-05
``` is the output. looks ok

Comment: `absolute_error` wants two vectors that hold the same thing. `ana_direct[i]` is of type `std::vector<Dune::FieldVector<double, 3>>`. What is the type for `num_direct`? (It comes from the `driver->solveMEGForward` function, and appears to be `std::vector<double>`.)

Comment: num_direct is a std::vector<double>. Could it be due to the output I added above? It seems ana_direct consists of a vector of a vector of (vector dim 3).